# Pandas: replacing part of a string from elements in different columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace, cell

I have a dataframe where numbers contained in some cells (in several columns) look like this: '$$10'

I want to replace/remove the '$$'. So far I tried this, but I does not work:

```
replace_char={'$$':''}

df.replace(replace_char, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Can you specify the error you're getting?

Comment: @ annicheez theres no error, theres simply no effected result. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example close to the approach you are taking would be:

```
df[col_name].str.replace('\$\$', '')
```

Notice that this has to be done on a series so you have to select the column you would like to apply the replace to.

```
    amt
0  $$12
1  $$34

df['amt'] = df['amt'].str.replace('\$\$', '')
df
```

gives:

```
  amt
0  12
1  34
```

or you could apply to the full df with:

```
df.replace({'\$\$':''}, regex=True)
```

Comment: Awesome.  Please mark this as the solution if it worked for you.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi @B. Bogart. after repalcing the values, the type in the columns where there were replacements is set to object. it there a way to change this while doing the replacement, or it is necessary to add an additional line of code to change dtpes from object  to float or int?

Comment: You can add .astype('int').  So for example if you are applying to the full df you could do df.replace({'\$\$':''}, regex=True).astype('int')

Answer (score 1):

your code is (almost) right.
this will work if you had AA:

```
replace_char={'AA':''}
df.replace(replace_char, inplace=True)
```

problem is $$ is a regex and therefore you need to do it differently:

```
df['your_column'].replace({'\$':''}, regex = True)
```

example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,2,3,4,5,'$$6'],"B":[9,9,'$$70',9,9, np.nan]})


    A   B
0   1   9
1   2   9
2   3   $$70
3   4   9
4   5   9
5   $$6 NaN
```

do

```
df['A'].replace({'\$':''}, regex = True)
```

desired result for columns A:

```
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    4
4    5
5    6
```

you can iterate to any column from this point.

Answer (score -1):

You just need to specify the regex argument. Like:

```
replace_char={'$$':''}

df.replace(replace_char, in place = True, regex = True)
```

'df.replace' should replace it for all entries in the data frame.

Comment: Respectfully, this is a collaborative platform. It about solving problems together, not getting the right answer first. In addition, my answer is significantly different from yours. It might be a better solution for the person, which is what we're all aiming for. I did not copy your solution by any means.